# [typescript]: indexing object union type returns 'never'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Why e is `never` and is there a better way to express same idea in types?

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAglAvFA3lUkBcUA5AIZFQC%20AUHtPEsAEIba7gSFEBG51tsCZAGcW9ZGgA%20AhoxrtpyACrzMY4EIDaRWkQC6VOZAXAAsiTAssVKDagbFUAJaJjyyLsIwAHsABOJAGNgAB41IQAaVlpCRQoAPipqQ2gANQhfADEAV0QA4IcIHyQAExE1Nwg4lgAKDmMzMHtdAEoMKrgAe0dig34AYQALCACAaz6OxAAzRwBzFgAFEl9gRxIAG2CrWzsHZ1d2Dyg0zJy8xQT4gwCJoWAoa6nCQeGxiem5zC3bEkJqr1b0FUHkIOmsIAA6NYdGZ-cH8dAI4hkZqJAyTU4rCZQXw5aoPd5PIajcZTWatL42YF3CCCdSeWmaXQsDRYaJIogUSI4NncDn6bbWWw0hhCcGTDq%20GCBAbVWoAqoU7ZOSZQPFvDQQ2gtbCCpVK-EauEHACEct1Suo2woKKSOMQaqmzSAA)

Exact error text:

```
Argument of type 'Events' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  The intersection 'EventA & EventB' was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents.
    Type 'EventA' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2345)
```

Code:

```js
type EventA = { type: 'a' }
type EventB = { type: 'b' }
type Events = EventA | EventB
type EventType = Events['type']

type EventMap = {
    [T in EventType]: Extract<Events, { type: T}>
}

type VerFunc<T extends EventType> = (e: EventMap[T]) => void

type CheckConfig = Partial<{
    [T in EventType]: VerFunc<T>
}>

const conf: CheckConfig = {
    a: (x) => console.log(x.type === 'a')
}

function run() {
    const events: Events[] = [{type: 'a'}, { type: 'b'}]
    
    events.forEach((e) => {
        if (conf[e.type]) {
            // e is never! 
            conf[e.type]!(e)
        }
    })
}

run(conf)
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! I was so sure that I stumbled upon a rare case that didn't even searched properly.